# What is the right way to access buttons in list page form?

Tags: forms, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

In ax 2012 in form with template "**list page**" you normally cannot access the clicked method on the button. You are just not allowed to overwrite method `clicked

You can change this behavior by setting the button property "DisplayTarget" to the value "**Client**". Than you can change the code of `clicked` method. But it does not feel right.

Is there any way how to access clicked method better way? For example by using `*FormName*ListPageInteraction` which is linked in form properties?

P.S.: I know you can make menu item (action) -> and call some class. But when you do not want to open new form in new window (by using menu item [display]), but you want to change something on current form it feels even worse than overwriting clicked method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the [DisplayTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formtablecontrol.displaytarget.aspx) property to the value "Client" will [hide the button](https://dynamicsaxposed.wordpress.com/tag/display-target/) if used from Enterprise Portal. If you not plan to use the list page in EP then go ahead.

Otherwise you will have to put your code in the target form `init`or class `main` method.