# How to add a method for the click event of a button placed on action pane of a List Page

Tags: button, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I placed a new button on the action pane of a list page in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012.

I am then trying to override the clicked method for the same button, but, I am unable to find the options menu with the method override list.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606114/what-is-the-right-way-to-access-buttons-in-list-page-form) for your answer.

Setting the  DisplayTarget property of the button to the value "Client" will hide the button if used from Enterprise Portal and will enable you to override the `clicked` method. 
If you not plan to use the list page in EP then go ahead.

Otherwise you will have to put your code in the target form `init` or class `main` method.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I also found a dynamics forum post that I have shared in my answer.

Comment: You said "put your code in the target form init or class main method". Can you please put some more light on this? As, lets say, if I want something before the target form opens, in such case, what will I do?

Comment: I have a situation where I do need to use the button on EP as well and there is no target form.  All I have is a list page, called from a menu item.  I have a button that I want to update the status of the current selected record.  Having a MenuItemButton that calls into a Class (would have to be a brand new class to keep everything logically separate) just seems like overkill and messy.  Is that the only option?

Comment: Yes, this is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Microsoft Dynamics Community answer for the same.

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/65449.aspx